# Why does my print statement(python) work in my python 3.4.3 shell, but not the online compiler? Is it because it's a different version?

Tags: python, shell, python-3.x

```
print('OK! What would you like to know about? (Choose from ',end='')
```

This is the only part of my code that is not functioning when I compile it online(I am using Ideone). It works fine on my python 3.4.3. shell. Is it a format problem?

Comment: What is the error you see? Also did you select `python` or `python 3` as the language?

Comment: I forgot to choose python 3. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

When selecting the language at [Ideone](http://ideone.com/8X2EXP), pick `python 3`.